# Running bash script in a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-jobs

I am trying to run an external *bash* script using the below `yaml` file.

The script is inside the `/scripts/run.sh` folder. I have also given the `defaultMode: 0777`

This is the error I get.

```
sh: 0: Can't open /scripts/run.sh
```

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  script.sh: |-
    echo "Hello world!"
    kubectl get pods
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: script-configmap
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  labels:
    app: script-job
  name: script-job
spec:
  backoffLimit: 2
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - command:
            - sh
            - /scripts/run.sh
          image: 'bitnami/kubectl:1.12'
          name: script
          volumeMounts:
            - name: script-configmap
              mountPath: /scripts
              subPath: run.sh              
              readOnly: false
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: script-configmap
          configMap:
            name: script-configmap
            defaultMode: 0777
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file name is `script.sh` and not `run.sh`

Try

```
containers:
    - command:
        - sh
        - /scripts/script.sh
```